# how do i get a instant variable from a class and put it in a if statement with an input

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi I m trying to create an if statement to check for an instant variable that if it's an instance variable then it should do something

so far I have got this

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, maths, english):
    self.maths = maths
    self.english = english

exam = test(maths, english)

testchecker = input("which test")

if testchecker == self.english == true:
print("you have passed the test")
```

Comment: Can you provide an expected input and output? Is the user meant to input something like the string "english"?

Comment: the string will be checked if its available in instant variable so if someone types English it will print you have passed the test that's what I m trying to achieve

Comment: What are the `maths` and `english` variables meant to hold in `test(maths, english)`? Just the strings "maths" and "english"? Will they ever hold anything else?

Comment: You should definetely read an introduction into python syntax. There are many mistakes in these few lines of code. But to give you a first hint: strings are defined with quotation marks (eg. "maths")

Comment: yes it will have a string and numbers yeah i forgot to put ""

Answer (score 0):

Try using python hasattr() method.This takes an object and search parameter(attribute) and returns a boolean(true or false )if the object has  that attribute.Eg.

```
   def subject_checker(self, subject):
       if hasattr(self, subject):
           print("you passed {}".format(subject))
```

This will check if the subject(math,english) is an attribute of the class.